# Query Pulling the same post twice

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, custom-taxonomy, query

After seeking help and failing, I managed to write a query for Wordpress that does exactly what it's suppose to do, however it pulls the post that it's suppose to in twice. I've stared and stared at the markup and I can't see why it's doing it. Here's the query:

```
<?php 
$the_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'tax_query' => array(
        'taxonomy' => 'supplier-tax',
    ),
) );

while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

<?php 
    $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'supplier-tax');
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        $termID[] = $term->term_id;
    } 

    $my_query = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type' => 'supplier',
        'tax_query' => array(
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => '$termID',
        ),
    ) ); ?>

    <?php while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
        <p class="supplier">Supplied by <strong><?php the_title(); ?></strong></p>
        <img src="<?php the_field('logo'); ?>">
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

If anybody could help, or point out where I'm going wrong so that i can learn from it, I'd really appreciate it.

I've been told that it's because the loop is running twice, but i'm not sure how tpo fix that.

Comment: [`WP_Query` `tax_query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters)

Comment: Could you help?

Comment: Ok, I have deleted my answer. Now everything make sense, feel free to search my profile for related posts, I have done a few with your basic requirements. :-)

Comment: Your link says "0 posts", thank you for your help. Should I leave my anser with mine then for now?

Comment: Ok, don't know how that happened, but just then type "related posts" in the search box and hit search. You will get a lot of results which you can play with. As for your answer, it depends on you

Answer (score 0):

I solved it:

Just in case anybody ever has any trouble querying a post with the same `term` of a `Taxonomy` in another `Post Type`. I'll post my answer below because I finally solved it on my own.

```
<?php 

$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'supplier-tax');
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    $termID[] = $term->term_id;
}

$the_query = new WP_Query( array(
 'post_type' => 'supplier',
 'tax_query' => array(
     array(        
        'taxonomy' => 'supplier-tax',
        'terms' => $termID,
      )
    ),
) );

while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

   <p class="supplier">Supplied by <strong><?php the_title(); ?></strong></p>
   <img src="<?php the_field('logo'); ?>">

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

I hope this helps someone because this was hard to find a solution too.

Comment: `tax_query` should be an array of an array

Comment: I don't understand, It works? what should i change it too?

Comment: I have updated your answer to be correct

Comment: Thank you very much, is there any chance you can explain what your change did and why it needed doing? just so I understand?